# How to use service name instead of External IP/domain name for "security.oauth2.resource.tokenInfoUri"

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Spring cloud with OAuth2. I have 4 applications as mentioned below:

1) Eureka server : Service Registery.
2) zuul as Api Gateway
3) Auth server - which is returning the access_token to client after successful authentication.
4) Resource server - wants to validate token before giving access to resource.

I used the below configuration in application.properties:

```
security.oauth2.resource.tokenInfoUri=http://localhost:9600/oauth/check_token
security.oauth2.client.client-id=resourceServer-client
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=secret
```

I dont want to give hard coded ipaddress / hostname for "tokenInfoUri" in application.properties.
I want to access the auth server by its service name as there can be multiple instances of Auth server.

How can i do that ?

I checked the code how tokenInfoUri works in spring boot using oauth2 and found that 
`ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration -> RemoteTokenServicesConfiguration -> remoteTokenServices()` 
method where tokenInfoUri us retrieved from ResourceServerProperties.java as @ConfigurationProperties.

I dont want to use JWT token for token verification. I want to verify using remote call from Resource Server to AuthServer.

Comment: could you find solution to this? I'm looking for same thing